# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause why is here an error?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What is wrong with my linq statement, what am I doing wrong?

```
if (this.selectLBU.HtUsers.Any())
{
    reportRowItems = (from r in reportRowItems
                      from bu in r.User.HtBusinessUnits
                      where bu.LocationBusinessUnitId == selectLBU.LocationBusinessUnitId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to add select clause to tell what data you require from query. This [**msdn article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) describes the basic query operation and structure.

```
 reportRowItems = (from r in reportRowItems
                   from bu in r.User.HtBusinessUnits
                   where bu.LocationBusinessUnitId == selectLBU.LocationBusinessUnitId 
                   select r 
                  ).ToList();
```

To get combination of both tables you can use projection.

```
reportRowItems = (from r in reportRowItems
                   from bu in r.User.HtBusinessUnits
                   where bu.LocationBusinessUnitId == selectLBU.LocationBusinessUnitId 
                   select new {r.AttributeName1, r.AttributeName2, bu.AttributeName1}
                  ).ToList();
```