# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause on core method

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I am getting the error when coding the query in LINQ:

```
var shortsms = await (from url in _dbContext.UrlBank
                      where url.LockBatchId ==
                          (from batch in _dbContext.LockBatch
                           where batch.LockBatchId.Equals(38)
                                 && 
                                 url.IsAssigned == 0 
                                 && 
                                 url.IsLocked.Equals(1)
                           )
                      );
```

in the result I need the firstOrDefault of ShortUrl in UrlBank.

Comment: What is your error? We need a description of it - preferably the exact string. Is it an error thrown by the application or an unexpected or undesirable result?

Comment: This is not a valid LINQ query.

Comment: Duplicate of [A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause why is here an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489436/a-query-body-must-end-with-a-select-clause-or-a-group-clause-why-is-here-an-erro)

Comment: " I need the firstOrDefault " so then you should call `FirstOrDefault` at the end, but don't forget to select the `url.ShortUrl`

Answer (score 1):

you need to select the output values.

Something like:

```
var shortsms = await (from url in _dbContext.UrlBank
                                      where url.LockBatchId ==
                          (from batch in _dbContext.LockBatch
                           where batch.LockBatchId.Equals(38) && url.IsAssigned == 0 && url.IsLocked.Equals(1) select batch.BatchId) // or whatever
                      select url.ShortUrl           // <---
               ).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); // if you use the QueryableExtensions
```

Atleast that is what the error message mean.

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows because you are missing **two** select clauses. It should be something like:

```
var shortsms = await (from url in _dbContext.UrlBank
                          where url.LockBatchId ==
                      (from batch in _dbContext.LockBatch
                           where batch.LockBatchId.Equals(38) && url.IsAssigned == 0 && url.IsLocked.Equals(1) select batch.Id) select url.ShortUrl);
```